# Input string C++ double chevron

Tags: c++, visual-c++, shunting-yard

I'm currently trying to use a double chevron in a string for "<<" and ">>" to represent bit shifting. However, my program does not seem to recognize using double chevrons for any input. If I change it to any other string, it works perfectly.

derpleft will work, however "<<" will not work.

```
keywords_["derpleft"]  = keywords_["<<"] = make<BitShiftLeft>();
keywords_["derpright"] = keywords_[">>"] =  make<BitShiftRight>();

dictionary_type keywords_;

typedef std::map<string_type,Token::pointer_type>   dictionary_type;

typedef std::string string_type;
```

Comment: Why do I have a feeling this has to do with using `char` for something that it can't hold?

Comment: It's a string, not a char.

Comment: keywords_["derpleft"]  = keywords_["<<"] = make<BitShiftLeft>();
keywords_["derpright"] = keywords_[">>"] =  make<BitShiftRight>();

derpleft works, not <<

It's made up of: typedef std::string string_type;

Comment: Are you actually inputting two less than signs, and not gullets or something?

Comment: I'm quite sure that I'm using << and >>.

Comment: Your program is upside down.  The compiler reads from top to bottom.

Comment: I just took segments out of it to show that keywords is a string.

Comment: How are you getting your tokens? We need more code than this to help.

Comment: As Tawnos said, we need more code. Nothing looks in the pseudo-code you've posted. But then again, nothing *really* looks wrong in pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

I just don't understand this statement:

```
keywords_["derpleft"]  = keywords_["<<"] = make<BitShiftLeft>();
```

It seems you want `<<` and `derpleft` to point to (store) the value returned by `make<BitShiftLeft>` call. In that case, why not simply it as follows:

```
keywords_["derpleft"]  = make<BitShiftLeft>();
keywords_["<<"] =  make<BitShiftLeft>();
```

You may store the value of `make` call in some local variable (`auto` keyword preferred).

And most importantly, you did not mention what the problem is!

Comment: It's *very* common usage to do `x = z = somefunction()` to set z and x to the output of somefunction(). Splitting that into two different calls with result in `somefunction()` being called twice (which you may not want to do) and can be harder to maintain.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of that! But it doesn't look good in the code posted above. `map::operator[]` will be called as LValue, then RValue, then LValue. I haven't tried, but how what about `keywords["<<"]` call - one call or two calls?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to close this thread, but the issue was I did not set a boolean to true in one of my editor functions. It was simply a logic error that I created.